# Jquery html length in IE

Tags: jquery

I had to made a special advertise module to my friend's site, and our problem is the advertisement doesn't appear in IE.
We send a special code to the advertisement server, and our block is disappeared by default. If we get longer text in $(document).ready, we display the advertisement block.

Our code before loading the page looks like this (I've changed our special numbers to xxx):

```
<div id="my_ad-0">
  <div class="content">
   <div id="bmone2n-xxxxx.x.x.x">
    <noscript><div style="display:inline"><a href="http://go.cz.bbelements.com/please/redirect/xxxxx/x/x/x/"><img src="http://go.cz.bbelements.com/please/showit/xxxxx/x/x/x/?typkodu=img&keywords=" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0" alt="" /></a></div></noscript>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The #my_ad-0 element is dissapeared by default. Then comes the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if ($("#my_ad-0").exists()) { //exist is a local function the check this block whether exists
  //alert('text #0: ' + $("#my_ad-0 .content").text().length);
  //alert('html #0: ' + $("#my_ad-0 .content").html().length);
  if ($("#my_ad-0 .content").html().length > 355) {
    $("#my_ad-0").css('display', 'block');
  }
 }
});
```

I examine the length of the HTML within #my_ad-0 .content. If it's longer than 355 chars, my block will be appeared (it works in major browsers, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari), but in IE doesn't, because IE says that the length of the block is 55 character. (IE doesn't count the characters within `<noscript>`) At api.jquery.com I found there is a bug in IE when using html() function, but I don't know how to proceed and solve this problem in IE. Currently I change manually the code to

```
if ($("#my_ad-0 .content").html().length > 355 || $.browser.msie)
```

but it's not to funny :) Any idea?

Comment: Yes, I tried and comes back with 0 in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try to change the logic behind the decision whether to display the element or not.

".html().length > 355" doesn't seem like a good practice to me. Can't you make this decision based upon something else e.g. an html attribute?

```
<div id="my_ad-0" class="visible">...</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the ad-server doesn't give back any error code or something if that region is empty. I tried in so many ways how to find out whether an advertisement is active in the region, and this was the only one which worked. But it wasn't tested correctly in IE.

Comment: Can you give an example with the contents of <div id="my_ad-0"> where you want the div to be hidden?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. The content of <div id="my_ad-0"> is in my original question. The response of the ad-server goes inside the <noscript> tag (changes the content of <noscript>). Currently I'm waiting for the reply from the operator of ad-server if I can change the code as mentioned by Briganti.

Comment: Have you tried something like $("#my_ad-0 .content").innerText or $("#my_ad-0 noscript").innerText? I can't really test it myself because in IE9 (the version I currently have installed) your code works as you expected.